# how to monitor malloc?

Tags: kernel, performance, ram, memory-usage

I want to create a module to calculate memory allocations of each process. I searched so much but I couldn't find anyway to make the kernel call my module whenever a process requests memory allocation. Is there any way to do that? if not what is the best performance command for checking if there has been a change in memory so I know when to call `ps` for analyzing. I don't want to call ps all the time because that has a very low performance. Currently I'm thinking about using `free` or `vmstat`. So which one of them or any good option that I'm missing has the best performance?

Comment: So is it the C standard library function `malloc()` you want to monitor or is it the Linux memory allocator which `malloc()` uses?

Comment: linux memory allocator. but I just though every process is probably using malloc:D.

Comment: crossposted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412680/how-to-get-notified-on-each-memory-allocation-deallocation